# Python word to id representation

Tags: python, nlp, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to represent a set of words by numbers. I have this code so far:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import itertools
docs = ["select", "max", "income", "from", "data", "where", "revenue", "between", "20", "40"]

# split documents to tokens
tokens_docs = [doc.split(" ") for doc in docs]

# convert list of of token-lists to one flat list of tokens
# and then create a dictionary that maps word to id of word,
# like {A: 1, B: 2} here
all_tokens = itertools.chain.from_iterable(tokens_docs)
word_to_id = {token: idx for idx, token in enumerate(set(all_tokens))}
```

However, there is one restriction - when the token itself is already a number, I need to assign the same value as the number (in the word_to_id dictionary).
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if else` statement inside dictionary comprehension.

```
{token: idx if not token.isdigit() else int(token)
             for idx, token in enumerate(set(all_tokens)}
```

This will return `{'4': 4, '5': 5, 'df': 1, 'dfg': 4, 'fd': 0, 'fg': 3}`
if the input is `['fd', 'df', '5', 'fg', 'dfg', '4']`

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more condition inside you dict comprehension, and to make it shorter, use shorthand for `if` expression : `what_if_True if if_statement what_if_else`. Like this:

```
word_to_id = {token: token if token.isdigit() else idx for idx, token in enumerate(set(all_tokens))}
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation would be nice. That will help other users as well.